# How can I select a complete folder instead of a single file while cloning user SuperDuper in OSX for backup?

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine, backup, superduper

I want to select the who lang comp lab folder for backing up (cloning) using SuperDuper software in OSX but it just allows me to select one file as an image. lang comp lab folder is inside mgserver folder which is a shared one. I have attached some photos which can depict this much better.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Any reason you NEED to use SuperDuper? I believe SuperDuper only accepts disks/DMGs as the source…

Comment: I ended up going with CCC